# Ruby on Rails simple_form as: :string changes CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I'm working on an existing RoR project and several simple_form fields have `as: :string` set. This parameter is causing one of my validations (which checks that the value is a positive number) not to be executed. I tried simply removing the `as: string` parameter but this completely changes the way that the form is displayed. I can't seem to find any indication that this parameter would have a direct impact on the CSS. Is there a tag that it adds that I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Full Field:

```
= f.input :amount, as: :string, :input_html => {maxlength: 10}, label: false, :hint => false, :wrapper => false, placeholder: "e.g. 100000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple_form uses your model validations to generate a lot of the CSS.  You can override the class and make it use something else.  Changing the data_type though is not a good approach, instead write a css class that gives you the size/shape you want.

```
= f.input :amount, :input_html => { maxlength: 10}, label: false, Wrapper: false, placeholder: "e.g. 1000000", class: "input class here"
```